How to instruct EF Core to fetch a value of CreatedAt column during update/SaveChanges
I have a model like this:
class Client 
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    ...
    public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
}

with the following type configuration (all other fields have default configuration):
builder.Property(p => p.CreatedAt)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("now() at time zone 'utc'")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);

When I execute an update operation I don't want to provide a CreatedAt value, i.e. I want it to always remain the same, hence in my API contact I don't even accept CreatedAt value for PUT (update) endpoint.
What I want is to ignore CreatedAt field during Update and this is the reason for Metadata.SetAfter... . However, after SaveChanges() the CreatedAt field remains null/default value.
I would like to somehow instruct EF Core to fetch value of CreatedAt field during an Update operation even though I don't update it. Is there any way to achieve that?
I know that it's possible to use something like Reload() method to reload all the fields but it means that for 1 update operation an application will always execute 2 requests to the database. And the only reason for the second request is just to get value of CreatedAt field, which doesn't sound good to me.

just to be clear, you can see that the CreatedAt value is properly set during the create operation?

you'll probably need to show your Update endpoint and related code.

I think you want SetBeforeSaveBehavior not SetAfterSaveBehavior

Which DBMS are you using? now() is not a valid SQL Server function. And the addition of at time zone suggests you should be using DateTimeOffset, not DateTime.

@RichardDeeming I'm using Postgres and it's a valid syntax for Npgsql EF Core provider. And the value is correctly assigned during creation, it's just it's not pulled from db during an Update

A CreatedAt field would be populated on Insert. Update wouldn't ever change it. A normal update operation should fetch and update an entity properties from a modified DTO/Viewmodel so you would have the CreatedAt at that point and time. Since this is a computed property you should protect the setter since code should never be able to change the CreatedAt timestamp:
 public DateTime CreatedAt {get; protected set;}

From there I would remove the Metadata.  From there after you insert a new entity, the CreatedAt value should be populated after saving. For update operations avoid using the Update method such as:
var order = new Order { Id = orderId, .... };
_context.Update(order);
_context.SaveChanges();

or worse, in a Controller action passing detached entities around calling Update() with an entity materialized from the client. The reason you should avoid this approach is that it can be prone to data tampering (request altered in ways you don't expect and overwriting data that should not change) and Update() generates an UPDATE SQL statement for all (non-generated) columns every time even if values haven't changed. By using EF's change tracking and copying values across you gain the benefits of:

Ensuring the update row is present and valid.
Only copying across values that are allowed to change.
Generating an UPDATE SQL statement for the values that actually change, and only if at least one value actually changes.

.
var existingOrder = _context.Orders.Single(x => x.Id == order.Id); // we have access to CreatedAt if you want to inspect it during an Update.
existingOrder.ValueThatCanChange = order.ValueThatCanChange; 
// ... 
_context.SaveChanges();

Here EF's change tracker takes over and will compose an UPDATE statement only if values change, and only for the values that change. CreatedAt won't be touched.
To help avoid manually copying properties one at a time you can use a Mapper like Automapper or Mapperly to define the allowed mapping for what can be copied over when performing the update. I.e. if only 6 fields are expected to be edited you can ensure that only those 6 possible values get copied across.

So, I guess there is no way to achieve what I want but I shouldn't even try to do that according to your comment. Hence, it seems to be a common scenario to make 2 DB calls per 1 update operation.

It can be avoided, but especially in web applications where you don't easily have a particularly efficient option to live poll to notify users of concurrent changes, and the inherent vulnerability to manual changes in POST payloads, you don't gain anything avoiding it. Reading an entity by ID is a fast operation and provides info about concurrent alterations plus building a concise UPDATE statement reflecting only what changed which cannot be done with Update().

In you DBContext you can do this
  public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("CreatedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("UpdatedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    

This will automatically update the created and updated appropriately.
Here is an example DBContext
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Test.Data
{
    public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options)
          : base(options)
        {
            this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(60);
        }

        public DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }


        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("CreatedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Property("UpdatedAt").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
                }
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


Yes, I have something similar in my DbContext, but issue I'm facing is not related to this. I was asking about a scenario when an entity is already inserted into a database (postgres in my case). And a client make an Update request to this entity. I have code like DbSet.Update(entityFromClient). And the issue I'm facing is that after such update  CreatedAt value of entityFromClient object remains null/default. I wanted to somehow instract EF Core to pull the value of the CreatedAt field during an Update operation even though I don't update it.
